# Multiple Forms in an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form which two divs that contain different 'forms' (i.e login and register forms).  The login div allows registered users log in, while the register div allows new users create a new account. Now I'm trying to validate input entered into the form. I got the javascript working for the register div but it's not working for the login div. Please how to i make the javascript work for the second div? Do i have to create different forms?

UPDATE:
Here's the javascript code:

```
function validateForm(){
        //create variables for tracking validation
        var valid=true;
        var msg;




        //validating the lastname field
        document.getElementById('lname').onkeyup=function(){
        if(document.getElementById('lname').value.length==0){

            document.getElementById('lnameerror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('lnameerror').style.color='red';
            valid=false;
            document.getElementById('lname').focus();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('lnameerror').style.display='none';
        }

        }

        if(document.getElementById('lname').value.length==0){

            document.getElementById('lnameerror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('lnameerror').style.color='red';
            valid=false;
            document.getElementById('lname').focus();
            msg='Please enter your last name';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('lnameerror').style.display='none';
        }


        //validating the firstname field
        document.getElementById('fname').onkeyup=function(){
        if(document.getElementById('fname').value.length==0){
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.color='red';
            document.getElementById('fname').focus();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='none';
        }

        }

        if(document.getElementById('fname').value.length==0){
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.color='red';
            valid=false;
            document.getElementById('fname').focus();
            msg='Please enter your first name';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='none';
        }






        //checking to see if password matches

        if(document.getElementById('cpword').value!=document.getElementById('pword').value){
            msg='Password does not match, please try again.';
            valid=false;
        }


        //Display alert on error
        if(valid==false){
            alert(msg);
        }

        return valid;
    }
    function signin_validate(){
        //VALIDATION FOR SIGN IN FORM
        //validating the password field
        document.getElementById('signin_pwordl').onkeyup=function(){
        if(document.getElementById('signin_pword').value.length==0){
            document.getElementById('signin_pworderror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('signin_pworderror').style.color='red';
            document.getElementById('signin_pword').focus();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('signin_pworderror').style.display='none';
        }

        }
        document.getElementById('signin').onclick=function(){
        if(document.getElementById('signin_pword').value.length==0){
            document.getElementById('signin_pworderror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('signin_pworderror').style.color='red';
            document.getElementById('signin_pword').focus();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('signin_pworderror').style.display='none';
        }
        }
        //validating the email field
        document.getElementById('signin').onclick=function(){
        if(document.getElementById('signin_email').value.length==0){
            msg='Please enter your email address';
            valid=false;
        }
        }

        //Display alert on error
        if(valid==false){
            alert(msg);
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="Accounts.php" method="post">
  <div id="maincontent">
      <h1>Sign In Or Register</h1>
      <div id="login">

          <h2>Sign In</h2>
              <div>
                  <label for="signin_email">Email Address*: </label><input id="signin_email" type="email" placeholder="E.g you@yourdomain.com"  autofocus maxlength="50" /><span style="display:none;" id="signin_emailerror" name="signin_emailerror">*Please enter your First Name</span>
              </div>
              <div>
              <label for="signin_pword">Password*: </label><input id="signin_pword" type="password" maxlength="24"   /><span style="display:none;" id="signin_pworderror" name="signin_pworderror">*Please enter your First Name</span>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <button type="submit" id="signin" name="signin" value="Sign In" onclick="return signin_validate()">Sign in</button>
              </div>
      </div>

  <h2>OR</h2>

      <div id="register">
     <h2>Register</h2>
          <div>
                <label for="fname">First Name*: </label>                        
                <input id="fname" name="fname" maxlength="30" type="text"  /><span style="display:none;" id="fnameerror" name="fnameerror">*Please enter your First Name</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="lname">Last Name*: </label><input id="lname" name="lname" maxlength="30" type="text"  /><span style="display:none;" id="lnameerror" name="lnameerror">*Please enter your Last Name</span>
          </div>


            <button type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Register" onclick="return validateForm()">Register</button>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: please post your code and explain proper requirement

Comment: I've posted the code, Please check my edited question.

Comment: I hope my answer below will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two Forms, one for login and other for register. The advantage of two Forms is with the user can press "Enter" for submit the form in both cases.

```
    <form name="formLogin" id="formLogin" action="Login.php" method="post" onsubmit="login_validate()">
      <div id="maincontent">
          <h1>Sign In Or Register</h1>
          <div id="login">

              <h2>Sign In</h2>
                  <div>
                      <label for="signin_email">Email Address*: </label><input id="signin_email" type="email" placeholder="E.g you@yourdomain.com"  autofocus maxlength="50" /><span style="display:none;" id="signin_emailerror" name="signin_emailerror">*Please enter your First Name</span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                  <label for="signin_pword">Password*: </label><input id="signin_pword" type="password" maxlength="24"   /><span style="display:none;" id="signin_pworderror" name="signin_pworderror">*Please enter your First Name</span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <button type="submit" id="signin" name="signin" value="Sign In" onclick="login_validate()">Sign in</button>
                  </div>
          </div>
</form>    
      <h2>OR</h2>
        <form name="formRegister" id="formRegister" action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="signin_validate()">
          <div id="register">
         <h2>Register</h2>
              <div>
                    <label for="fname">First Name*: </label>                        
                    <input id="fname" name="fname" maxlength="30" type="text"  /><span style="display:none;" id="fnameerror" name="fnameerror">*Please enter your First Name</span>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for="lname">Last Name*: </label><input id="lname" name="lname" maxlength="30" type="text"  /><span style="display:none;" id="lnameerror" name="lnameerror">*Please enter your Last Name</span>
              </div>


                <button type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Register" onclick="signin_validate()">Register</button>
              </div>

          </div>
        </div>

</form>
```